# Freeze first two columns in a Flexigrid

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I am using [Flexigid](http://flexigrid.info/), and I need to freeze the first two columns. It has to always be visible.

I searched like anything, but I did't find any use full information. I need the solution using only Flexigrid. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of Flexigrid you are using, however, there should be a fixed property that you can set on the column itself. Just set *Frozen* equal to the rightmost column you want frozen and all columns to the left of it should be frozen as well. It takes an integer corresponding to the column number.

In C# for WPF/Silverlight/Lightswitch development, it would be the following:

```
_flex.Columns.Frozen = 2;
```

To unfreeze set `Frozen = 0;`.

Comment: Oops apparently you were using a totally different flex grid from a different vendor and platform.  Good luck